# Hide name of sender in Nebular chat UI

Tags: css, nebular

I have follow instruction from https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/chat-ui/overview#nbchatformcomponent to create custom chat component.

The problem is how can I remove The name sender from this component?

[image: Chat screen]

```
<nb-chat [title]="recievername" size="medium" [status]="theme">
<nb-chat-message large
*ngFor="let message of chatService.messages"
[message]="message.text"
[reply]="message.user.sendername"
[sender]="message.user.recievername"
[date]="message.date"
[avatar]="message.user.avatar"
>
<nb-chat-form (send)="sendMessage($event, avatar)" [showButton]="true">
```

**CSS** it's just this

```
::ng-deep nb-layout-column {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
:host {
  display: flex;
}
nb-chat {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 770px!important;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour sorry i forgot it , Done

Comment: Can you add custom CSS to your project?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Done

Comment: Can you use DevTools Browser Console? Or do you know the ID or Class of the sender name element?

Comment: What happens if you remove this: `[sender]="message.user.recievername"`?